# Getting sub text of an element using Java and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have a Table with header (th) elements in it.  The th may contain text but most likely a child element of the th will contain the text.  Problem is the sub element aon't always be the same label or the same depth.  For instance

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>
    <span>Here is some text</span>
  </th>
  <th>
    <a>This is some text</a>
  </th>
  <th>
     <span><a>Lower Level</a></span>
  </th>
  ..
 </tr>
 </thead>
 </table>
```

so my find.elements xpath is 
"//div[@id = 'gridClaimListing']/div[1]//table//thead/tr[2]//th" (the table is located under that div).

So for each element I guess I could do another find like ".//*[@text]" or maybe ".//*[text()]" but that might be a pain.  Is there a way I can get that text from the *th* element even if the *th* itself has no text in it at is level?  I believe *element.getText()* may just get the element-level text and no sub level.

Comment: Did you try `.getText()` on the last <TR>? What did it return? Please read [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `<th>` does not contain the text you need and only the child elements have the text, you can trysomething like this:

```
List<WebElement> parentElems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'gridClaimListing']/div[1]//table//thead/tr[2]//th"));

for(WebElement parent: parentElems) {
    // for each parent element (th), fetch all it's children
    List<WebElement> childElements = parent.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));

    // display text of all child elements
    for(WebElement descendant: childElements) {
        System.out.println(descendant.getText());
    }
}
```

Here we leverage the xPath `".//*"` to fetch all child elements of an element.

Comment: I'd say that internal for loop is irrelevant; as `parentElems` is identifying all three `<th>`

Comment: @kushal. internal for loop for child elements? I did that so it works for cases where a `<th>` tag has more than 1 child

Comment: ohh.. that's nice thinking

Comment: These are actually column headings in a grid.  One is just blank (i.e. no text) but a check box.  I want to get the position in the heading that the text is, and then get that same position cell in the data row.  I am going to make a list of the headings and use indexOf().  So even if there is not text I need to count is as a heading so the data position stays in sync.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah. That's a whole different question, but once you fetch the child element, in the inner for loop you can do a check if the webelement is a checkbox. if so, add a placeholder in the list else add the text.